# Xamarin.Forms IOS Simulator Issue

Tags: xamarin.forms, ios-simulator, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio 2022 has been paired successfully with macOS and the simulator is working with MAUI application but the simulation is not showing in Xamarin.Forms application.

- Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise is up-to-date.
- Xamarin.Forms and all NuGet packages are up-to-date.
- macOS, Xcode, and Visual Studio for mac are up-to-date and working successfully.

Comment: Add more details and show relevant images or code to your question.

Comment: *” the simulation is not showing …”* - I don’t understand what you are saying. What is missing, from where?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved by downgrade Xcode from 14.3 to 14.2

Comment: Excellent! You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem. Also, `Xcode14.3` support is still in progress referring to [[META] Xcode 14.3 Support for Xamarin, .NET 6/7 and MAUI · Issue #17561 · xamarin/xamarin-macios · GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/17561) and follow the progress.